# How to round scientific (symetric / mathematic) in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rounding

I know (most) of the background of different rounding rules and the binary representation of floating point numbers in computers. So my question is not about why this happens but only how I can achieve my goal to **round scientific**.
Please correct me if I am wrong but possible synonyms are *symetric rounding*, *mathematic rounding*<del>, round to even</del> or *bankers rounding*. Correct?

In the example below the value `2.5` (from `mean([2, 3])`) should be rounded to `2` and `3.5` (from `mean([4, 3])`) should be rounded to `3`. But it does not.

With Pythons in-build routines

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> round((3+4)/2)
4
>>> round((3+2)/2)
2
```

I tried `numpy` in the assumption that this is for scientific use.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.round(np.mean([3, 4]))
4.0
>>> np.round(np.mean([3, 2]))
2.0
```

I found out about Pythons own `decimal` module where `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` is in my opinion the correct round mode. But maybe I am wrong here?

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding
'ROUND_HALF_EVEN'
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(4)) / 2
Decimal('3.5')
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(2)) / 2
Decimal('2.5')
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 1
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(4)) / 2
Decimal('4')
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(2)) / 2
Decimal('2')
```

I assume that I have a miss inunderstanding here.

Comment: TIL: I quote the numpy doc: "For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard [R9] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten."

Comment: "Please correct me if I am wrong but possible synonyms are symetric rounding, mathematic rounding, round to even or bankers rounding." I don't think that listing is correct. Specifically, "round to even" should not round a tie to an *odd* number like 3 as you desire. What you describe seems to be ["Round half toward zero" or "Round half down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer), depending on which behaviour you want for negative values.

Comment: Various rounding methods are discussed here, https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html.  `python/numpy` is doing   'round to even' (subject floats limitations).  Looks like you want 'round down'.  But have you thought about negatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of @MisterMiyagi comment the rounding rule I was asking for is `decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN` in Python.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding
'ROUND_HALF_EVEN'
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(4)) / 2
Decimal('3')
>>> (decimal.Decimal(3) + decimal.Decimal(2)) / 2
Decimal('2')
```

Comment: That was an exclusive "or" in my quote. "toward zero" and "down" are not the same thing, ``ROUND_HALF_DOWN`` cannot express them both.

Comment: In that case it is better if you would answer the question or edit my answer. This is what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: It's very difficult for me to correct an answer when I still don't know what the question is actually asking for...